# Обновить конкретную ячейку таблицы

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Для работы с excel используется oledb. При выполнении update ошибка: Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров. Какие еще параметры нужны в запросе - не понимаю

```cs
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=3\"";
(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
 var dbCmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Разделы 1-2$C4:C4] SET F3 = 12345", connection); 
dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Покажите итоговую connectionString. Возможно, в пути к файлу содержатся пробелы. Нужно весь путь взять в кавычки.

Comment: Используйте `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` для составления строки соединения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, подключение работает - проверено на других запросах

Comment: `path + filename` замените на `Path.Combine(path, filename)`

Comment: @aepot, то же самое

Comment: А я и не говорил, что поможет. Я просто вам показал, как правильно склеивать части пути в один путь.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо) Но ведь выше  сказал, что подключение есть

Answer (score 0):

Решение простое, но буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит логику Microsoft. В запросе нужно указывать только 1-е имя столбца(F1 при HDR=no). Т.е. не нет разницы между:

```
UPDATE [<Лист>$D4:D6] SET F1 = <значение>
UPDATE [<Лист>$A4:A6] SET F1 = <значение>
UPDATE [<Лист>$C4:C6] SET F1 = <значение>
```